# special character is giving null value

Tags: php, database

I am having 1 database.In that I am having one tabel.
  I am doing json parsing in this code.
  I have used this php code for retrieving value:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
    text-align: right;
}
</style>
</head>

<?php

echo getdata($_REQUEST['lastupdate']);

function getdata($lastupdatedate){


    $obj = json_decode($json);



    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","Password");


    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("roster", $con);

    $query = "select * from statedeathtax_v2 where LastUpdated > '".$lastupdatedate."' order by LastUpdated";

    $rs = mysql_query($query) or die($query);

    //print_r($rs);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){

    $record[] = $row;

    }



    $data = json_encode($record);



    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');

    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');

    header('Content-type: application/json');

    return $data;

}

?>
```

Here this code is not displaying special characters like "$".
  When I am throwing query in this code,it showing null values for the columns which is having special characters.
I am not getting the issue.

Comment: [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/function.htmlentities.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved prob :

Updated Code :

```
<?php

echo getdata($_REQUEST['lastupdate']);

function getdata($lastupdatedate){


    $obj = json_decode($json);



    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","Password@123");
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);

    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("roster", $con);

    $query = "select * from statedeathtax_v2 where LastUpdated > '".$lastupdatedate."' order by LastUpdated";

    $rs = mysql_query($query) or die($query);

    //print_r($rs);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){

    $record[] = $row;

    }



    $data = json_encode($record);



    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');

    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );

    return $data;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For mysqli_connect:**

```
$conecta = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "dbase") 
or print (mysql_error()); 

$conecta->set_charset('utf8');
```

Check more on
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.html